# Enabling fast refresh on materialized view with geometry

Tags: oracle, materialized-views, oracle-spatial

I have a seemingly simple problem, for which materialized views seem to be the ideal solution, however I do not get it to work efficiently, and maybe the answer simply is: "Oracle does not allow it at all", but I am hoping I am overlooking something stupid.

Problem: due to some historic decision I have a table containing geometries from two countries, stored in the coordinate system of one country. I now want to create a materialized view using a shared coordinate system. So  in effect, the simplest query to achieve this was:

```
select thr_ident, thr_status, geom from 
  ((
     select thr_ident, thr_status, sdo_cs.transform(sdo_cs.transform(thr_geometry, 327680), 8307) as geom
     from th_threat 
     where thr_origin in (6,61, 11, 9) 
   ) 
   union all 
   (
     select thr_ident, thr_status, sdo_cs.transform(thr_geometry, 8307) as geom
     from th_threat 
     where thr_origin not in (6,61,11,9) 
  ))
```

The geometry is only created once, but I would like to keep the state in sync (for visualisation purposes). So I added a materialized view log on `thr_ident` and `thr_status`:

```
create materialized view log on th_threat 
with sequence, rowid (thr_ident, thr_status)
including new values;
```

and created the materialized view, and hoped it would automatically stay in sync whenever the original source data was changed ('on commit').

But apparently `refresh on commit` is not possible when using objects, but having a `fast refresh` would be close enough, if it was efficient/fast enough.

I assumed assumed `union all` was not really helping, I rewrote this into a single query as follows:

```
create materialized view th_threat_mv 
--  refresh fast on demand
as  
select 
  rowid rid, thr_ident, thr_status, 
  case 
    when thr_origin in (6,61, 11, 9) then 
      sdo_cs.transform(sdo_cs.transform(thr_geometry, 327680), 8307)
    else   
      sdo_cs.transform(thr_geometry, 8307)
  end as geom    
from th_threat;
```

But still fast refresh is not enabled.

The result of `explain_mview` shows only complete refresh is possible, and the others are all disabled (a bit hard to read/deduce for me, I could dump it if requested, but it repeats three times `object data types are not supported in this context`).

The `mtune_view` gives me the following error:

```
QSM-03113: Cannot tune the MATERIALIZED VIEW statement

QSM-02083: mv references PL/SQL function that maintains state
```

So now I am guessing this is caused by the `SDO_CS.TRANSFORM` ?

Theoretically I would assume a fast refresh would be possible/simple:

- create the row on insert (with the appropriate transformations)
- update the state when the `thr_status` is changed (or calculate the single row in its entirety

but either I did not correctly implement it or Oracle is not able to deduce it is a actually a simple 1-1 materialized view (because it contains a geometry? a case statement?).

I can always brew my own solution, using triggers, but was wondering if I am overlooking something obvious to get the material view working efficiently (as it seems a perfect fit). Any help/insights/comments are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Oracle deems it a complex query because of the geometry function and fast refresh is not possible on complex queries. 
You will need to do a complete refresh.
Thanks

Sabiha